# Where are the English pluralization rules for ActiveSupport defined?

Tags: ruby, activesupport, pluralize

I found the ActiveSupport inflector class. Where can I find the code that initializes the inflector for English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The English rules are in ActiveSupport (specifically in lib/active_support/inflections.rb).

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveSupport [inflector.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/34d1e5d04d2e2583bf28fc2365f43d5917e2c648/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb) file includes all the inflection libraries and modules.

If you want to customize it, there's a file called `inflections.rb` in your Rails `config/initializers` path.

By default it contains

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new inflection rules using the following format
# (all these examples are active by default):
# ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
#   inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
#   inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
#   inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
#   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
# end
```

You can edit it to customize the `Inflector` behavior.